# How to retrieve all possible combinations given a sequence of keys from a dictionary with list values

Tags: python, biopython

I have for instance this dictionary

```
d={'M':['ATG'],'D':['GAC','GAT'],'E':['GAA','GAG']}
```

What I'd like to have as an output given a sequence of keys is a list with all possible sequences. (could be a string as well, in which all the possible sequences would be in separate lines "\n")

```
sequence = "MDE"
```

So, the output should be the following:

```
['ATGGACGAA','ATGGACGAG','ATGGATGAA','ATGGATGAG']
```

What I've tried so far is the following, but of course it's not what I want:

```
seq_trans = ''

for aa in sequence:
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == aa:
      for item in v:
        seq_trans= seq_trans + item
print seq_trans
```

And what I get for "MDE" is:

```
'ATGGACGATGAAGAG'
```

Comment: MED doesn't seem to match your output; do you mean MDE?

Comment: yes, you're right DSM... I've just changed it... and yes, the order matters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use  [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here, it returns Cartesian product of the input iterables.

```
In [78]: seq="MED"

In [79]: ["".join(x) for x in product(*(d[y] for y in seq))]
Out[79]: ['ATGGAAGAC', 'ATGGAAGAT', 'ATGGAGGAC', 'ATGGAGGAT']
```

Comment: Hmmph.  Beat me: I was writing `[''.join(p) for p in product(*(d[c] for c in sequence))]`.  Whenever the question involves "all possible" or "every possibility", you know `itertools` is going to be involved. ;^)

Comment: I was writing the same thing too, except the generator expression part.

Comment: "One obvious way to do it", as they say!

Comment: `itertools`: making a python programmer's life easy since py2.3.

Comment: hey, what if I read a sequence from txt file?? I tried your answer, and an error occurs: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <genexpr>
KeyError: '\n'

Comment: @ÀngelBa use `strip()` when reading data from text files. It removes the `\n`, which in your case might be causing the error.

Comment: uff! thank you very much, the error is solved now. Sorry, I'm a noob